# 401.1 errors when access IIS web application from new subnet

Tags: iis, authentication, subnet

I am currently reorganising subnets in my organisation. **New** subnet is 10.65.0.0/24 and **old** subnet is 172.16.0.0/21.

Clients in new subnet are not able to access a web application in 172.16.9.0/24 - they get prompted for credentials then a 401.2 error (traffic is routed but authentication fails).

Clients in an old subnet (even the same clients moved to a different network location) are able to access without being presented with credential requests or any errors.

The webapp runs in IIS6 - no changes have been made to the web app - the only thing (I am aware) that has changed is the network location of the clients.

**Update 1**: I've simplified the test case down to eliminate any odd passthrough to SQL server etc.  Now I'm just requesting a static text file from the server - I still get the 401.2 error.  If I switch from Integrated authentication to Basic Authentication, then the page is delivered fine.

**Update 2**: Looks like the apps affected are limited to using NTLM - apps that use Kerberos authentication seem to work fine.

**Update 3**: The new subnet is currently routed to the subnet with the servers in it via a Cisco Meraki MX firewall - there aren't any firewall rules denying traffic but this does seem to be the major difference between the two subnets.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Do you have any software or hardware firewalls in between the subnets? Or a Software fire wall on the server which identify the new Subnet as untrusted?

Comment: No firewall or ACLs between the subnets yet.

Comment: In your AD site and service, does your new subnet are created/defined ?

Comment: and can you validate if your DNS suffix are correctly set in that new subnet too with an ipconfig /all, as that 401 error can happen if so; *Therefore, authentication fails if the FQDN or the custom host header that you use does not match the local computer name*

Comment: @yagmoth555 - What do you mean by "DNS suffix correctly set"?  Set where?

Comment: @dunxd, may be you can give [Fiddler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966510(v=vs.85).aspx) a try.

Comment: @dunxd  please see there for an example; http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x550/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-05/7851.PrtScr-capture_5F00_35.jpg make sure they match from a subnet to another, as it's the dhcp server that send those options usually.

Comment: A bit similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/446743/iis-7-401-2-error-by-hostname-but-not-by-ip-address and to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921017/http-401-2-unauthorized-error-with-windows-authentication-from-remote-machine I'd check Security log on DC

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with Kerberos.  I enabled trust for delegation for the computer account in Active Directory, and things started working.